# Is the Excel function CUBEMEMBER supported by Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Currently I am reading xlsm formatted spread sheet and which has CUBEMEMBER function. I am using following dependency in `pom.xml`.

This is not supporting CUBEMEMBER function. Does any one help which Java API support CUBEMEMBER function to read excel and proceed?

> artifactId - poi-ooxml
>
> version-3.14

Comment: You need to add your code and a better explanation to the questions so the community can review it.

Comment: Fixed your back to front title. Hard to see what JavaEE has to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html):

> **Status**
>
> The code currently provides implementations for all the arithmatic operators. It also provides implementations for approx. 140 built in functions in Excel. The framework however makes it easy to add implementation of new functions. See the [Formula evaluation development guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html) and [javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/formula/functions/package-summary.html) for details.

So, not *all* Excel functions are supported out-of-the-box, which seems to include `CUBEMEMBER`.

You have to implement that yourself then, and you can then help others by becoming a contributor to the open-source community, instead of just a consumer, by adding the implementation to the project.